How to estimate a similar utility function to that found in Engelmann and Strobel (2004)
I hope this is the right place to ask such question.
I have experimental data from a binary dictator game and I am wanting to estimate the relative importance of different types of preference motives.
I have $k$ players i.e. the Dictator and a known charitable organization such that $k \in \{D, C\}$.
I have $j$ allocations such that $j \in \{1, 2\}$, where $j=1$ represents an inequitable allocation i.e. $(x_{1D}, 0)$ and $j=2$ represents an equitable allocation i.e. $(x_{2D}, x_{2C})$, where $x_{2D} = x_{2C}$. All payoffs are varying at the participant level $i$ based on their performance in two real effort tasks with each one uniquely mapping onto each allocation $j$.
There is four main preference motives I want to estimate: linear self-interest (classical utility), efficiency (total surplus), maximin, and self-centered advantageous inequity aversion (F&S not ERC).
The above are defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
Self_{ij} = x_{jD}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Eff_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^{2} x_{jk}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
MM_{ij} = \text{min}\{x_{jk}, k = 1,2\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
FS\beta_{ij} = -\text{max}\{x_{jD} - x_{jC}, 0\}
\end{equation}
The model does not include disadvantageous inequity aversion because if the charity in allocation $j=2$ ever has the more than the worker in allocation $j=1$ than it must also be true that they could have just as much by choosing allocation $j=2$, hence, the values for the $\alpha$ parameter always return 0 and should be dropped.
Including the above in a empirical specification provides us with the complete model we are looking to estimate:
\begin{equation}
V_{ij}(x) = \gamma_{1}Self_{ij} \ + \ \gamma_{2}Eff_{ij} \ + \ \gamma_{3}MM_{ij} \ + \ \gamma_{4} FS\beta_{ij}
\end{equation}
Given this functional form is linear, can I not just run a logit estimation? I tried doing this, but got collinearity issues with $MM_{ij}$ and $FS\beta_{ij}$, when $Self_{ij}$ and $Eff_{ij}$ were already present in the model.
I did a slightly different approach and manually estimated for $\gamma_{4}$ with the following code, but my brain is so fried that I do not know how to extended it to the full model.
See stata code below (its not a minimal working example, but sufficient enough to point me in the right direction):
// Fehr & Schmidt estimates 

local step = 1000

matrix errors = J(`step' + 1,2,.)
matlist errors

forvalues i=0(1)`step' {
    preserve
    local beta=`i'/`step'
    gen U_A = 0
    replace U_A = pWorker1 - `beta'*(pWorker1 - pCharity1) if pWorker1 >= pCharity1
    replace U_A = pWorker1 - `beta'*(0) if pWorker1 < pCharity1

    gen U_B = 0
    replace U_B = pWorker2 - `beta'*(pWorker2 - pCharity2) if pWorker2 >= pCharity2
    replace U_B = pWorker2 - `beta'*(0) if pWorker2 < pCharity2

    gen y_hat = 0
    replace y_hat = 1 if U_A > U_B
    gen y_error_sq = (y_hat - worker_keep)^2
    sum y_error_sq
    scalar smse = r(sum)
    display smse
    local x=`i'+1
    matrix errors[`x',2] = smse
    matrix errors[`x',1] = `beta'
    restore
}

matlist errors

This produces a very small estimate of 0.124 at the lowest smse value, which tells me the average dictator was not bothered too much by inequity aversion when they earned the endowment and it was not windfalled, however, I am also operating in a monetary stakes range that is very low so they might also just me insensitive to inequity aversion within my specific range of incentives.
Is there any way to get around the collinearity issue or given the low estimate should I just drop inequity aversion and focus on self-interest and efficiency? I guess this question slightly deviates from my original question in the title.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update (11/28/2024): I now realize where the collinearity issues are happening. I just had to sleep off a long day apparently.
So for the $MM_{ij}$ concerns, we have $Self_{ij} + MM_{ij} = Eff_{ij}$.
And for $FS\beta_{}ij$, we have $Self_{i,j=1} = Eff_{i,j=1} = -FS\beta_{i,j=1}$
I think I might just drop inequity aversion estimates and focus on self-interest and efficiency for the remainder of the analyses.
